# Leaflet format values from geojson

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization, leaflet

Is there a way to format the values for different locales contained in a geojson as they are displayed in Leaflet?

In the Web application Im developing, all data is contained in a geojson. I have to use different language versions which require also a different format for numbers and currencies. The values are displayed in popups, legends and D3 charts. In the charts, I can use formatter functions from D3 to get the right locale setting: comma-separated decimals.

How can I can I display the values as comma-separated decimals and also currency in different format using javascript and leaflet from a geojson?

Any suggestions?

**Edit**: Matthew Bloch suggested using d3.locale to format the values on the client. It makes a lot of sense. I will try to find an example. Could globalize.js be a solution or maybe a just a JavaScript function?

Here is a sample area and code:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Monduiz/b1gcq54d/)

Sample code:

```
var onEachFeature_LMA = function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
            layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            click: zoomToFeature
        });

var Popup = feature.properties.AreaName + '</b><br />No diploma: ' + 
    feature.properties.NoDipTot + '%' + 
    '<br />High school: ' +
    feature.properties.HSTot + '%' +
    '<br />College: ' +
     feature.properties.ColTot + '%' +
     '<br />University: ' +
     feature.properties.UnTot + '%';
layer.bindPopup(Popup);         
}
```

**EDIT2:**

Just a quick addition that I thought might be interesting for folks looking into this. The answer provided works but I have decided to use D3 as suggested by Matthew for localization. With D3 I can format everything I may need: dates, currencies, numerals etc.

Define a locale to use and then use numberFormat or timeFormat, etc. Its dynamic with current D3 and doesn't need a recompile like it used to.

```
var enCA = d3.locale({
  decimal: ".",
  thousands: ",",
  grouping: [3],
  currency: ["$", ""],
  dateTime: "%a %b %e %X %Y",
  date: "%Y-%m-%d",
  time: "%H:%M:%S",
  periods: ["AM", "PM"],
  days: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
  shortDays: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
  months: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
  shortMonths: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
});

var  format = enCA.numberFormat("n");
format(3,4) //3.4
format(10000) //10,000
```

Comment: you might update the fiddle so it provides an example that needs to be fixed to do what you are asking (right now, your fiddle looks like it's working just fine...)

Comment: The example is displaying values with a "." decimal. I want to use d3.locale to format the data to a French locale with "," for the decimal. I need the data to display in the right locale for popups, legends and charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if this doesn't fit your requirements, but what about just using a simple string replacement to change dots to commas like this:

```
//globally replace '.' in oldString by ',' and save it to formattedString string
formattedString = oldString.replace(/\./g, ',');
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sw0zuesy/).

You could also extend the function to take a location as an input and format the string based on a `switch` statement.

Comment: Brilliant! Could this function be also applied to a leaflet legend? (http://jsfiddle.net/Monduiz/dhz4doch/)

Comment: Of course, it's just a simple string replacement - you could use it on any string (or any type that can be casted to a string). The easies way would be to apply the function to each individual legend element like `lower = [dotToComma(0), dotToComma(0.16), dotToComma(0.33), dotToComma(0.44), dotToComma(0.51)]` and so on. You might want to do this more elegant by extending the function to take an array as an input or something like that.

Comment: Krxldfx, I cant thank you enough. This is brilliant and solves 2 of the three elements I need to deal with. The last is for D3 charts but d3 has functions to specifically deal with this so I will look into that. Thank you! Internationalization is not easy!

Comment: Just as a note: The important thing here is that neither the legend nor the popup need a real **number**. They are fine with strings. You would run into problems if you use the string replacement - that returns a string - on something that needs actual numbers, e.g. for some mathematical operations.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. This is just for displaying values so it should be perfect. This is why I was looking for a solution like this one. Its important that the data in the geojson remains numeric and the formatting be applied for display only.